# Replace IP with domain name

Tags: php

I'd like to replace the IP address in an url to a normal domain name. In short:

```
Change
http://123.456.789.025/images/2015/a/

Into
http://images.domain.com/images/2015/a/
```

Anyone know how to do this? I couldn't find it here on SO.

Thanks!

Comment: The URL is input to your PHP script?  Do you already know the domain, or do you need to lookup a name by IP?

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem to me

Comment: we know and have the domain running on our server. We just need to replace the IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically not possible, without all kinds of hacky methods. If a SPF record is registered you could *guess* which domain is linked to the IP, but that's pretty much it. An IP is most commonly shared by hundreds or even thousands and more domains. So *if* you could find out, by querying a nameserver, which domains are linked to the IP address, even then you wouldn't know which one of the thousands of TLD's is the correct one. The only way to find out I can think of is grabbing the page using the TLD as URL *and* with the IP as URL, and compare the outputs. But this is really tricky, as when the page is serving dynamic content, the output will be different (virtually) every request. And this would impose you'll have to do a request for every domain linked to the IP, until you've got a match.

Of course, when you know the ip's beforehand, just create an array:

```
$ip2domain = array(
    '123.123.123.123' => 'mydomain.com',
    ...
);
$url = 'http://'. $ip2domain['123.123.123.123'] .'/images/2015/a/';
```

**EDIT** I saw you're edit, that you know the domain etc. In that case, just deconstruct the url with php's native **[parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)** function. For constructing the url, use **[http_build_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)**:

```
$url = 'http://123.456.789.025/images/2015/a/';
$parts = parse_url($url);
$parts['host'] = 'example.com';
$final_url = http_build_url($parts); // http://example.com/images/2015/a
```

(it sometimes pays off to look on php.net instead of SO ;))

Comment: Thanks Giorgio! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be always IP there (in other case this replaces some another IP in query string):

```
$url = join($host, preg_split('/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/', $url, /*limit*/1))
```